# Training Keras model with fit_generator and TFrecords

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I would to like to train my ConvNet with Keras. Following some tutorials I wrote something like this.

I don't know if it is good, in particular I have some doubts about the usage of generators to train my model.

Before, I fed train procedure with numpy-array generators, but I read that it is possible to use tfrecords to improve performances.

At a first time I converted the tensors into numpy arrays in the `create_dataset` function below (before 'yielding' them) but I read later that

> There is indeed a more efficient way to use Dataset without having to
>   convert the tensors into numpy arrays.

so I tried to edit my code in this sense using 
`input_image=tf.keras.Input(tensor=x)` and `model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=compute_loss, target_tensors=[y])`.

Before I didn't use neither`target_tensors` inside `model.compile`or `tensor=x` inside `tf.keras.Input` (I only specified input shape).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import compute_loss #my loss function

dataset_train_path="dataset_train.tfrecords"
dataset_val_path="dataset_val.tfrecords"

filepath_checkpoint="weights-best.hdf5"


Adam=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam
optimizer = Adam(lr=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)

BATCH_SIZE=32
TRAINING_SIZE=5717
VALIDATION_SIZE=5823
TRAINING_STEPS=TRAINING_SIZE//BATCH_SIZE
VALIDATION_STEPS=VALIDATION_SIZE//BATCH_SIZE

"""-----------------Here I define my generator-----------------"""
def _parse_function(proto):

    keys_to_features = {'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                        'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)}


    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(proto, keys_to_features)

    parsed_features['image'] = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features['image'], tf.float16)
    parsed_features['label'] = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features['label'], tf.float16)
    return parsed_features['image'], parsed_features["label"]


def create_dataset(filepath, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE):

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filepath)

    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function, num_parallel_calls=8)
    dataset = dataset.repeat()
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(100)
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)

    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    image, label = iterator.get_next()

    image = tf.reshape(image, [BATCH_SIZE, 416, 416, 3])
    label = tf.reshape(label, [BATCH_SIZE, 75, 25])

    while True:
        yield image, label

"""-----------------Here I create my train/val generators-----------------"""
training_generator=create_dataset(dataset_train_path)
validation_generator=create_dataset(dataset_val_path)

"""-----------------Now I can define my model-----------------"""
x,y=next(training_generator);
def net():
    input_image=tf.keras.Input(tensor=x)
    inputs=tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,3,padding='same', activation='relu', name='conv_1')(input_image)
    inputs=tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(name='norm_1')(inputs)
    ...
    ...
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(75, 1, name='conv_13')(inputs)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_image, outputs=outputs)
    return model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    model=net()
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=compute_loss, target_tensors=[y])
    model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,validation_data=validation_generator, epochs=1000, max_queue_size=1000, steps_per_epoch=TRAINING_STEPS, validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Now training is going quickly but I suspect some errors somewhere. Could you help me?

EDIT: If I put directly the datasets inside `fit_generator` I obtain the following:

```
>>> train(model, DataGenerator, filepath_checkpoint="weights-best-tiny-test.hdf5")
Epoch 1/5000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tiny.py", line 239, in train
    model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,validation_data=validation_generator, epochs=5000, max_queue_size=100, steps_per_epoch=TRAINING_STEPS, validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS, callbacks=callbacks_list)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1586, in fit_generator
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 211, in model_iteration
    batch_data = _get_next_batch(output_generator, mode)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 323, in _get_next_batch
    generator_output = next(output_generator)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 767, in get
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 743, in get
    inputs = self.queue.get(block=True).get()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 680, in next_sample
    return six.next(_SHARED_SEQUENCES[uid])
TypeError: 'Iterator' object is not an iterator
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about your problem? Is this code working?

Comment: Yes it is working, but I don't know if it is working fine. What makes me suspicious is that training works very quickly. I want be sure that all images of my dataset are really passed to the training procedure.

Comment: Keras handles iteration, so you don't need to use dataset iterator. Also paste your traceback

Comment: Thank you @Sharky . I have no errors, I 'just' wonder if my program does what i should do. Does not fit_generator need an iterator to work?

Comment: No it doesn't need iterator, but don't forget to set batch/epoch size. You need to set step per epoch. And you have wrong order of dataset operations, shuffle, repeat etc. Read more https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets

Comment: Sorry if I cannot understand, but why should the order of dataset operations change the resulting dataset? I read tensorflow guide about datasets but there is nothing about that. Also I set at the beginning both BATCH_SIZE and TRAINING_STEPS (which is my epoch size). Finally, if i put only the dataset inside fit_generator I receive some errors (edited the original message with traceback).

Comment: order usually doesn't change resulting dataset, it's just better to stick to a reccomended order in terms of efficiency. you need to use `model.fit`

Comment: Ok, now with model.fit it works with dataset as parameter. Unfortunately it appears slow and the GPU usage has decreased to 3-4% (before was about 20%). Is there any reason about that?

Comment: please make yourself familiar with dataset api performance guide, and look into your parse function